# Get current matching regex-rule

Tags: javascript, regex, while-loop, vendor-prefix

I try to check for a given `RegExp`-rule in a string and need to get the current matching rule.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var prefixes = /-webkit-|-khtml-|-moz-|-ms-|-o-/g;
var match;
var str = '';

while ( !(match = prefixes.exec(str)) ) {
    str += '-webkit-';
    console.log(match); // => null
}
```

The `match` is `null`, but how can I get the current matching-rule (in this case `-webkit-`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't asking for any groups in your regex, try surrounding your regex in parenthesis to  define a group, e.g. `/(-webkit-|-khtml-|-moz-|-ms-|-o-)/g`.

Various other issues, try:

```
var prefixes = /(-webkit-|-khtml-|-moz-|-ms-|-o-)/g;
var match;
var str = 'prefix-ms-something';

match = prefixes.exec(str);
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var prefixes = /(-webkit-|-khtml-|-moz-|-ms-|-o-)/g;
var str = "-webkit-adsf-moz-adsf"
var m;
while(m = prefixes.exec(str))
    console.log(m[0]);
```